# Horizontal scroll on table doesn't work on iOS Safari

Tags: javascript, ios, css, reactjs, safari

I'm writing a React app, and I can't get a horizontal scroll on my table working on iOS Safari only. It seems to work on everything else.

My JS file

```
<div className={styles.parent}>
  <div className={styles.wrapper}>
    <table className={styles.table}>...</table>
  </div>
<div>
```

My CSS

```
.parent {
  width: 100%;
  overflow-x: hidden; 
}

.wrapper {
  position: relative;
}
.table {
  background: transparent;
  border-spacing: 12px 0;
  min-width: 1em;
  display: block;
  overflow-x: auto;
  max-width: none;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch !important;
}
```

Comment: You might be able to solve this be adding an event listener on your **container** that watches for the scroll event. See [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8944824/ios-safari-onscroll-event-within-nested-element?rq=1) for more information.

Answer (score 3):

Please try this one i hope it wil helpful to you.

```
.parent {
  width: 100%;
  overflow-x: auto; 
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Okay, then please see this i hope that's the same as you are looking for.

http://jsfiddle.net/Rohanatfiddle/P8dne/468/